# Primefaces autocomplete is very slow to load large data in JSF page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete search using 'Primefaces Autocomplete' tag for morethan one lack options to show. When I enter a character in the autocomplete box,which is having 30000 options, it is taking more than 40 seconds to update the options in the autocomplete box and the screen is getting struck until the list is updated. In the server side it's taking 15 milliseconds to iterate but when returning to the Jsf page , it's taking more time. Please assist me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you attempting to display 30000 options in first place? Imagine that every option is a mere 100 bytes, that's thus already 3MB being transferred and processed. That's a lot of work. Moreover, no single sane human in the world would ever scroll every single item of such a list. It makes therefore logically sense that you'd better reduce that list to fewer items. This is not exactly a JSF problem as it's in the context of this question merely a model view presenter and HTML/JS code generator. You'd have had exactly the same performance problem when using any other server side framework.

Comment: Maybe you could benefit from the attribute minQueryLength

Comment: @jaqenH'ghar: you mean looking at the showcase and reading the docs?